# httplib post call error

Tags: python, apache, httplib

I am trying to automate few http requests where, I have following POST call data which i captured from the web :

Method: POST 
Request Header :

POST /cgi-bin/auto_dispatch.cgi HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.226.45.6
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 244
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryhwDXAifvLs48E95A
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: http://10.226.45.6/auto_dispatch.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,kn;q=0.6
Cookie: TWIKISID=dce9a6aa10e33b708f5bbc2912f781ab

payload :

------WebKitFormBoundaryhwDXAifvLs48E95A
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="taskid"

123
------WebKitFormBoundaryhwDXAifvLs48E95A
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Submit"

Submit Form
------WebKitFormBoundaryhwDXAifvLs48E95A--

MY script is as follows :

```
  import httplib, urllib
     def printText(txt):
      lines = txt.split('\n')
         for line in lines:
           print line.strip()

     params = urllib.urlencode({'@taskid': 12524, '@Submit': 'Submit Form'})
     headers = {"Content-type": "multipart/form-data", "Accept":       "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"}
     conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("10.226.45.6", 80)
     conn.request("POST", "auto_dispatch.html", params, headers)
     response = conn.getresponse()
     print response.status, response.reason
     printText (response.read())
     conn.close()
```

I am getting the following error :

400 Bad Request

400 Bad Request
Bad Request
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.

Please help me to form a proper request .

Answer (score 0):

I Tried with the curl commands which worked for me :

curl --request POST 'http://10.226.45.6/cgi-bin/auto_dispatch.cgi HTTP/1.1' --data 'taskid=111&submit=submit'

curl --request POST 'http://10.226.45.6/cgi-bin/auto_free.cgi HTTP/1.1' --data 'submit=submit'